Postgres pgvector: errors when searching embeddings
I have a postgres db with a pgvector vector column containing my embeddings.
Inserting objects is not a problem. But searching trough embeddings gives an error.
conn = psycopg.connect(autocommit=True)
model = SentenceTransformer('multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1')
embedding = model.encode(query)
results = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY embedding::vector(384) <-> %s LIMIT 5", (embedding,))
for result in results:
    print(result)

Error: psycopg.ProgrammingError: cannot adapt type 'ndarray' using placeholder '%s'

You have to make sure you convert your numpy array to a list and pass it as a string to the query:
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY embedding::vector(384) <-> %s LIMIT 5", (f'{embedding.tolist()}',))

